# How to put two buttons in Horizontal field manager in blackberry for any device?

Tags: blackberry

I have two buttons in a horizontal field manager. one i want to put in left side of the screen and another in right side. How can i put them properly without implementing sub layout, so that it can work for all the device?

Comment: What happens if you put two buttons in a HorizontalFieldManager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think creating your custom manager is best way to layout controls.
but i think we can that

```
VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH);
        vfm.add(new ButtonField("button2",Field.FIELD_RIGHT));

        HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
        hfm.add(new ButtonField("button1"));
        hfm.add(vfm);
        add(hfm);
```

Edit:

if we are using HFM, it is the responsibility of HFM to align in horizontal.

So

```
 HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(FIELD_RIGHT);
        hfm.add(new ButtonField("button1"));
```

above code will place button1 to right.
but

```
HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
        hfm.add(new ButtonField("button1",FIELD_RIGHT));
```

above code will not align button right.
So when you are using HFM 
you need to give horizontal align of field in manager and vertical alignment in field.

When you are using VFM 
you need to give vertical alignment in manager and horizontal alignment in field.

Comment: I am writing the code like this:                                              HorizontalFieldManager hfm1 = new HorizontalFieldManager();
  m_btnDisagree = new ButtonField("I Disagree", FIELD_LEFT);                                                                     hfm1.add(m_btnDisagree);                                                                                     m_btnAgree = new ButtonField("I Agree", FIELD_RIGHT);                      m_btnAgree.setMargin(0, 30, 0, 0);                       hfm1.add(m_btnAgree);
  hfm1.setMargin(30, 0, 0, 30);
  m_vfmScreen.add(hfm1);

Comment: @ArindamMukherjee so is it working i don't think it will work.

Comment: using your code, it is working somehow. But i want some left margin and right margin for the two buttons.