# Adding vertical field manager within a horizontal field manager that itself lies in a vertical field manager-Blackberry

Tags: layout, blackberry, button, user-interface, layout-manager

I am creating 3 buttons in a horizontal field manager so that they are aligned in center of screen horizontally.

This is being done on a tabpane manager that contains 3 tabs.The implementation is within the first tab of the pane.All the code held in this pane is within a vertical field manager.

I have gone through the following link for creation of buttons
[How to put two buttons in Horizontal field manager in blackberry for any device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845438/how-to-put-two-buttons-in-horizontal-field-manager-in-blackberry-for-any-device)

It advises adding a vertical field manager to a horizontal field manager.In my code there is another vertical field manager that is holding this horizontal field manager.

Here is my code:

```
// setup the tab model with 3 tabs
  final PaneManagerModel model = new PaneManagerModel();
  model.enableLooping( true );

// setup the first tab   
   VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager( 
      Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH |
      Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL );
  LabelField lbl = new LabelField( "Content for tab 1", Field.FOCUSABLE );
  vfm.add( lbl );

//Add one button to the form normal way
 ButtonField gl = new ButtonField(" Group ",ButtonField.FIELD_HCENTER | ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
     // sms.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener());
     gl.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() 
      {
            public void fieldChanged(Field field,int context) 
            {
                  model.getView().jumpTo(1,PaneManagerView.DIRECTION_NONE); 
            }
       });
      vfm.add(gl)


//Second button
//SMS send from form
      ButtonField sms = new ButtonField(" Sms ",ButtonField.FIELD_HCENTER | ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
     vfm.add(sms);


//Adding horizontal field manager(MAIN IMPLEMENTATION)
HorizontalFieldManager buttonPanel = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_HCENTER | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
    buttonPanel.add(vfm);//Gives error at this point
   // buttonPanel.add(sms);
    buttonPanel.add(new ButtonField(" Send Mail "));
    add(buttonPanel);


 //Ideal way posted on that link
VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH);
    vfm.add(new ButtonField("button2",Field.FIELD_RIGHT));

    HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
    hfm.add(new ButtonField("button1"));
    hfm.add(vfm);
    add(hfm);
```

I am totally confused with the layout managers to be used here.
Please guide.Thanks